# Alert Dialog doesn't work, force close on launch

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

My `AlertDialog` doesn't work, the app closes on launch.

```
Button btn_disclaimer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_disclaimer);
    btn_disclaimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("DISCLAIMER");
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("TEST123")
                    .setNegativeButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();

                                }
                            });

            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();


        }
    });
```

What is wrong with it? I imported these guys:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
```

I'm new to Android, just creating some simple apps.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{gd.mkp.jd.de.gymnasiumdamme/gd.mkp.jd.de.gymnasiumdamme.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2216)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5140)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at gd.mkp.jd.de.gymnasiumdamme.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:279)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2170)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5140)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post a complete stack trace from logcat

Comment: you don't need the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`, you can pass `null` and it will still close the dialog when the user clicks Okay

Comment: There's a NPE in your `onCreate()` (line #279) and not in the `onClick()`. Possibly `btn_disclaimer` is null. In the future, please post stacktraces as text directly in the question and not as external pastebins or pictures.

Comment: stupid question - but how can i fix it? You're right^^

Comment: `R.id.btn_disclaimer)` Look in the xml layout file is the button if named like that. Check if `btn_disclaimer` is null before you try to set an on click listener with `if (btn_disclaimer==null) { Toast ( button is null ); return;}`

Comment: @user3503543 Start by finding what is line #279 in your MyActivity.java where the NPE occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like your btn_disclaim object is null. 
Reasons:

1) You use the wrong id when doing the findViewById(R.id.btn_disclaimer). Make sure the button you're trying to reference actually has this id.

2) The button XML layout you are trying to reference is not actually in the XML layout you are loading with this Activity. The id exists, and so you can compile the app, but the view in which it exists is not the one you are loading using setContentView(R.layout.whatever_your_activity_layout_is). Make sure you are loading the correct layout, or make sure your button layout is actually defined in the layout you are load for this Activity.